# How can I use PassportJS to create a new session?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js

I'm trying to build a bridge between two applications, so I am trying to use the same session that I get from Rails to authenticate a user in Node. The two applications have access to the same memcache, so one application just writes to it and the other one reads from it. Basically, I am authenticating the app from another application and I need to create a user session with Passport, how can I do that?

Edit: Right now, I'm leaning towards just writing a new strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a new strategy for passport that would check memcached and then finish the authentication process.